# Refresh Fb Comments Plugin

Tags: facebook, comments, refresh

I'm trying to add a link to allow a user to refresh the Comments plugin on my page so they can see other posts by other people.

I want to do it without refreshing the full page.

There's a html5 player on the page playing audio, hence me not wanting to interrupt that player.

Currently I'm using the standard -

I've tried the jQuery method of giving the div an id and having a header script which counts to 10 and reloads the div widget, it seems to reload the widget, but it doesn't update the contents of the comments plugin to show other's posts, just ones you've added yourself. To see all the updates you have to refresh the page fully, which I don't want to do.

I'm trying to avoid iFrames because of the height issues and extra scroll bars, etc.

Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: Show us some code, _how_ you tried refreshing the widget.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but you can use the [FB.XFBML.parse](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/) method to refresh plugins.

The only thing is that you'll need to first remove the old plugin from the dom, then add the new html5/xfbml placeholders (what you get from the comments plugin page when clicking "get code") and then use the `FB.XFBML.parse` method.